# How to deploy a ASP.NET MVC 4 app to web hosting provider sub-directory with Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, publish, web-hosting

I downloaded **Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Web**, created an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, click on **F5** and see a basic, functioning site with Database in Chrome:

[image]

Now I want to publish this to my web hosting provider (domainbox.de) which has "ASP.NET 1.1 to 4.0", but not to the main site (tanguay.de) but to a sub-directory (e.g. tanguay.de/test).

However, when I right-click on the solution name and choose publish, I can **upload via FTP**, but it seems to only be giving me the ability to publish to the **root of my domain**. This is how I remember how ASP.NET 2.0 worked as well--it was impossible to have multiple websites hosted in sub-directories.

[image]

**How can I publish this site to tanguay.de/test and then create another site and publish it to tanguay.de/test2, etc. Is that possible?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific and the technologies are WAY out of any support now. It also has no answers.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1):

In the Target Location field, you can put the full path to your site, e.g. tanguay.de/wwwroot/test2 (or whatever path it maps to).